# Download Latest Xcode Version on Macbook 2018

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, macos-catalina

I need Google Firebase for my app. But I just realized it requires Xcode 10.1 and I currently have Xcode 9.2. I can not update Xcode with my 2018 MacBook. I have already written a large amount of code and integrated firebase into my app. How can I get Xcode 10.1 on my laptop? I need any solution. I currently have the 2018 macbook with MacOS Sierra. Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to download it from the Mac App Store via the Software Update panel. Xcode updates will not delete existing Xcode Projects.

Comment: the macbook specifically says that the xcode update is incompatible, and that I would have to get a new macbook. I need a way to get xcode with the 2018 macbook.

Comment: Might need to update to Mojave first